# KMZ file displays correctly in Google Earth but not inside Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, kmz

I have a KMZ file that contains many placemarks inside.

When opened in Google earth the file displays the placemarks correctly. I can click on them and see the data for each placemark. See screen shot below which shows the placemarks appear on top:

[image: Google Earth]

I transferred the KMZ file to Google maps, and now I can't click on some of the placemarks. Only the top layer seems to work and I can see the placemarks behind everything but can't click them like I can in Google Earth.

[image: Google Maps]

I assume both programs function differently and that is why, but is there anything I can do to fix the KMZ file so it displays correctly inside Google Maps?